Estimate 3D location of a tracked point with Known Camera parameters and Distance
I want to estimate the 3D point of X̅₂,
X̅₂ = [ X₂         Y₂         Z₂ ],
by using known variables:

X̅₁ is at world origin,
camera intrinsics K,
camera extrinsics w.r.t. X̅₁, namely [R₁ ∣ t₁],
euclidean distance d₁₂, between X̅₁ and X̅₂,
image points; x̅₁, x̅₂ tracked by optical flow.

Please check the figure to have visual understanding of the problem.


Can this problem have a solution? 2D-3D mapping might be ill-posed.

How can I formulate this problem?

Do I need to know/calculate R₂ and t₂ extrinsics between camera and X̅₂?

or can I define a cost function to be minimized like this;

ObjFun​ = ∥x₂ − K[R₁ ∣ t₁]X₂∥

subject to d₁₂




We can assume X₂ is 0 to simplify the problem, if necessary.

It is the depth of X̅₂ w.r.t. X̅₁, in world coordinates.



Any ideas/comments would be very appreciated!
